# connected scrollable containers approach

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

So the idea of this design is:

- when I scroll the white area horizontally I need to always see the green area
- when I scroll the white area vertically I need to always see the blue area
- it's not the areas that should move, it's the content inside them

My current approach is to have 3 separate containers - the white area has `overflow: auto` so its scrollable, the green and blue areas have `overflow: hidden` so I can control their `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` properties. I listen to `scroll` event over the white area and update the green area's `scrollTop` and the blue area's `scrollLeft`

However, the problem is that it's a bit laggy, so I was wondering if there is another, better solution to that problem..

Regards!

Comment: so what I understood is when you scroll vertically in white area the blue area should move/scroll upwards.....and on horizontal scroll the green container should move right....Am I correct?

Comment: nope, both areas stay fixed, its just the content in them that scrolls.. so if you scroll vertically in the white area, the green area's content scrolls vertically too, same goes for the blue area with horizontal scrolling

Comment: I managed to solve it using ```position: sticky``` - check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: scroll
}
#g {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#b {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 50vw;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50vw;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="g">

</div>

<div id="b">

</div>

<div style="margin-left:55%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px; overflow: scroll; width: 1000px">
  <h2>Fixed Full-height Side Nav</h2>
  <h3>Try to scroll this area, and see how the sidenav sticks to the page</h3>
  <p>As you can see, if you remove the "position: fixed" from the "#b" and "#g" styling rules, they don't stay up, and they move as you scroll, but with them, they stay at the same place, and you might also want to add a <i><b>margin</b></i> as there is in the CSS too.</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <p>Some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, if you remove the *position: fixed* from the *#b* and *#g* styling rules, they don't stay up, and they move as you scroll, but with them, they stay at the same place, and you might also want to add a **margin** as there is in the CSS too.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, however I managed to solve it myself, check out my answer below

Comment: then what was your question?

Comment: please check out my answer a bit below and you will see what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the problem myself, this is what I came up with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
">

    <div style="
    display: flex;
">

      <div style="
    min-width: 200px;
    background: green;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
">content</div>
      <div>
        <div style="
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 1000px;
">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div style="
    height: 100px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use css position property. You can try using CSS flexbox layout. I solved this quickly like this.

This is the css part.

```
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container .g {
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(57, 156, 57);
  }
  .container .left {
    width: calc(100% - 220px);
    height: 100%;
  }
  .container .left .w {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .container .left .b {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgb(53, 135, 182);
  }
  .innerContent {
    width: 1800px;
    height: 1500px;
    background-color: grey;
  }
```

the body part

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="g"></div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="w">
      <div class="innerContent">32132</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```